# Unable to hide DIV when clicking outside using plain JS

Tags: javascript

I've been getting my feet wet with JavaScript and ran into this following issue.
Can someone please explain why id="list-container" won't hide when I click outside of the DIV?

```js
const listContainer = document.getElementById('list-container')

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    if (e.target != listContainer) {
        listContainer.style.visbility = 'hidden'
    }
})
```

```html
<header class="main-container">
        <div id="list-container">
            <ul class="ul">
                <li class="list-item"><a>List Item 1</a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a>List Item 2</a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a>List Item 3</a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a>List Item 4</a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a>List Item 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
    </header>

    <button onClick="document.getElementById('list-container').style.visibility='visible'" type="button" class="button">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Any errors in your console? Something like _"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')"_

Comment: No errors in the console. The id="list-container" DIV shows appears after clicking the button. But when I click outside of the DIV, nothing happens.
@Phil

Comment: So close! Have a good look at this line:
```listContainer.style.visbility = 'hidden'```

Comment: FYI, you might want `if (!e.target.closest("#list-container"))` to exclude clicks on children of the container too

Comment: Normally, `!e.target.closest("#list-container")` should be used in the condition. After all, if you click _inside_ `#list-container`, you either click the `#list-container` itself, or some descendant which is not the `#list-container`. You want to check if the click did not occur in the descendant or on the element itself.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You had a typo in your script. Use "visibility" instead of "visbility". But there was also a logical flaw in your script: The click event handler was effectively triggered multiple times. In the following script it will only be called once. The `listContainer.style.visibility = e.target.id==="btn" || e.target.closest(".ul")` expression then checks, which element was clicked and makes the `ul` either "visible" or "hidden":

```js
const listContainer = document.getElementById('list-container');

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.tagName);
  listContainer.style.visibility = e.target.id==="btn" || e.target.closest(".ul") 
   ? "visible" : "hidden";
})
```

```css
.ul {background-color:#ebe; width:200px}
li {background-color:#bfb; color:#0b0; padding:6px}
a {background-color:#ddf; color:#00f}
```

```html
<header class="main-container">
  <div id="list-container">
    <ul class="ul">
      <li class="list-item"><a>List Item 1</a></li>
      <li class="list-item"><a>List Item 2</a></li>
      <li class="list-item"><a>List Item 3</a></li>
      <li class="list-item"><a>List Item 4</a></li>
      <li class="list-item"><a>List Item 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

</header>
<button id="btn">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: _"The click event handler was effectively triggered multiple times"_... how do you figure that?

Comment: Well, in OP's version a click was listened to in the inline onclick assignment of the button AND in the `addEventListener`  assignment.

Comment: Ah ok, I see where you're coming from. I think OP's button is a bit of a red herring; they weren't asking about that one

Answer (score 1):

The First problem is that the property is called visibility and not visiblity

Here, the idea is to detect click events on the page and set the container’s display to none only when the target of the click isn’t one of the div descendants.

```js
document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  var listContainer = document.getElementById('list-container');
  if (!listContainer.contains(e.target)) {
      listContainer.style.visibility = 'hidden';
  }
});
```

```html
<header class="main-container">
  <div id="list-container">
      <ul class="ul">
          <li class="list-item"><a>List Item 1</a></li>
          <li class="list-item"><a>List Item 2</a></li>
          <li class="list-item"><a>List Item 3</a></li>
          <li class="list-item"><a>List Item 4</a></li>
          <li class="list-item"><a>List Item 5</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</header>

<button onClick="document.getElementById('list-container').style.visibility='hidden'" type="button" class="button">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: Nice, didn't know about [Node.contains()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains)

Answer (score -1):

So there are two reasons your button did not work. The first being that you are checking for clicks outside of the div to hide and the button is outside the div. Second, onclick has a lowercase C and also is simply used to call functions in the JS. Here I made a function which sets the visibility to visible and then also when the table it set to be hidden it is checked that the button was not hit.

```js
const listContainer = document.getElementById('list-container')

function returnVis() {
    listContainer.style.visibility = 'visible'
}

document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {

    if (e.target != listContainer && e.target != document.getElementById('visbtn')) {
        listContainer.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
})
```

```html
<header class="main-container">
        <div id="list-container">
            <ul class="ul">
                <li class="list-item"><a>List Item 1</a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a>List Item 2</a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a>List Item 3</a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a>List Item 4</a></li>
                <li class="list-item"><a>List Item 5</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        
    </header>

    <button id='visbtn' onclick="returnVis()" type="button" class="button">Click me!</button>
```

If you wanted the table removed entirely from the viewport then use

```
listContainer.style.display = "hidden"
```

and

```
listContainer.style.display = "";
```

Comment: When using console.log(e.target) and clicking on the li elements which log as anchor tags in the console, why does the DIV box disappear as well after I added the following to the code?

const li = document.getElementsByTagName('a')
and
e.target != li

Answer (score -3):

Use display:none

```
const listContainer = document.getElementById('list-container');

      document.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        if (e.target != listContainer) {
          listContainer.style.display = 'none';
        }
      });
```

Comment: There's a big difference between changing an element's visibility and removing it from the document flow. Why should OP use this over `visibility` (when spelled correctly)?